# PredictionIO pio status: Zookeeper exists failed

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, predictionio

I installed PredictionIO by **$ bash -c "$(curl -s https://install.prediction.io/install.sh)"**

and when I did **pio status**, it shows the following message:

```
[INFO] [Console$] Inspecting PredictionIO...
[INFO] [Console$] PredictionIO 0.9.5 is installed at /Users/jia.huang/PredictionIO
[INFO] [Console$] Inspecting Apache Spark...
[INFO] [Console$] Apache Spark is installed at /Users/jia.huang/PredictionIO/vendors/spark-1.5.1
[INFO] [Console$] Apache Spark 1.5.1 detected (meets minimum requirement of 1.3.0)
[INFO] [Console$] Inspecting storage backend connections...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Meta Data Backend (Source: ELASTICSEARCH)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Model Data Backend (Source: LOCALFS)...
[INFO] [Storage$] Verifying Event Data Backend (Source: HBASE)...
[ERROR] [RecoverableZooKeeper] ZooKeeper exists failed after 1 attempts
[ERROR] [ZooKeeperWatcher] hconnection-0x3035228, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Received unexpected KeeperException, re-throwing exception
[WARN] [ZooKeeperRegistry] Can't retrieve clusterId from Zookeeper
[ERROR] [StorageClient] Cannot connect to ZooKeeper (ZooKeeper ensemble: localhost). Please make sure that the configuration is pointing at the correct ZooKeeper ensemble. By default, HBase manages its own ZooKeeper, so if you have not configured HBase to use an external ZooKeeper, that means your HBase is not started or configured properly.
[ERROR] [Storage$] Error initializing storage client for source HBASE
[ERROR] [Console$] Unable to connect to all storage backends successfully. The following shows the error message from the storage backend.
[ERROR] [Console$] Data source HBASE was not properly initialized. (io.prediction.data.storage.StorageClientException)
[ERROR] [Console$] Dumping configuration of initialized storage backend sources. Please make sure they are correct.
[ERROR] [Console$] Source Name: ELASTICSEARCH; Type: elasticsearch; Configuration: TYPE -> elasticsearch, HOME -> /Users/jia.huang/PredictionIO/vendors/elasticsearch-1.4.4
[ERROR] [Console$] Source Name: LOCALFS; Type: localfs; Configuration: PATH -> /Users/jia.huang/.pio_store/models, TYPE -> localfs
[ERROR] [Console$] Source Name: HBASE; Type: (error); Configuration: (error)
```

As suggested in https://docs.prediction.io/resources/faq/, I tried to start HBase by **$ ~/PredictionIO/vendors/hbase-x.y.z/bin/start-hbase.sh**, but the same error remains.

What are other solutions that I can try? Do I need to install zookeeper manually? (I thought the quick install would already install it). Thanks!

Comment: you should check pio.log under $PIO_LOG_DIR for more info

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like HBase hasn't been initialized properly. First try doing `pio-stop-all` and then `pio-start-all`, and then try `pio status` again. If that doesn't work, then go ahead and run `pio-stop-all` again, and then look for a running instance of HBase by typing in the following command `ps aux | grep hbase`, and shut down the appropriate instance of HBase that is running (use `kill -9 <PID>`). After typing in `pio-start-all` again, you should be able to run `pio status` without the fore mentioned error.

----EDIT-----

Since you just installed PredictionIO, running `pio-start-all` should suffice. However, in my experience, if you are using HBase you may run into a situation where you have to kill the process manually as stated above.

Comment: Thanks Marco! I followed your suggestion all the way along till 'pio status'. However, the same error message shows there. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Prediction-IO has COMPLETELY LOST the plot and any viable product since Oracle bought them ! Nothing works anymore.. The actionML port is also broken. I suggest starting to look somewhere else for a ML-Toolkit

Comment: This is true, just a correction, Salesforce bought them, not Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

sleep for a number of seconds (100?) depending on your circumstances.
"waiting for 10 seconds for HBase to start" is not always long enough.
I execute pio status as late as possible in the startup script to save time (without sleep). Then pio status will always succeed.

Answer (score 0):

May be too late, but worked for me.

In your vendors find hbase-site.xml

Change /vendors/hbase-1.2.6/conf/hbase-site.xml

```html
<configuration>
<property>
      <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
      <value>file:///home/{your-user}/PredictionIO/vendors/hbase-1.2.6/data</value>
   </property>
   <property>
     <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
     <value>/home/{your-user}/PredictionIO/vendors/hbase-1.2.6/zookeeper</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this is an old post but writing this answer if someone visits this post then this might be helpful.

check hbase logs you may see `Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally 
java.io.EOFException` this exception was in my logs at least.

Traverse to the verion_2 dir under zookeeper dir in vendors/hbase

now `ls -ltr` the log files check for the latest file with 0 byte length. delete the file and restart the services and it should work fine.
I faced this issue yesterday and this resolved my problem.